# How can I reduce the sizes of the tables which are presented side by side, their internal texts and respective captions?

Tags: tables, captions, fontsize, scaling, size

I want to present two big tables (9 columns each) side by side.
For that I wrote this code:

```
\begin{table}
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Class 1 & Class 2 & Class 3 & Class 4 & Class 5 & Class 6 & Class 7 & Class 8\\\hline
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\\hline
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo}
}
\hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& Class 1 & Class 2 & Class 3 & Class 4 & Class 5 & Class 6 & Class 7 & Class 8\\\hline
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\\hline
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bar}
}
\end{table}
```

Output:
[image]

Tables overlap with each other. I cannot reduce the sizes of the tables, their internal texts and respective captions.

Mycode generated two warnings also:
[image]

Line 264 and 277 contain just closing braces `}` .

---

These are the packages I've used so far :

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea} 
\usepackage{mathtools}% ctan.org/pkg/mathtools 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

**Edit**

By following Pluton's suggestion in comment section, I've almost solved my problem except the right end of the right table is not aligned with the texts of the document.

[image]

Comment: For the top rows, do you have to repeat "class" in every cell? If not, that would fix your problem

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Do you use the `geometry` package? If so, please tell us wich options you selected.

Comment: The `graphicx` package is needed if you want to include images in your document. Since your code does not include any image, this package is unrelated to the issue itself. Please show us the line that starts with `\documentclass`.

Comment: Does "I cannot reduce the sizes of the tables, their internal texts and respective captions."  mean that you wouldlike to do that but you don't know how to or does it mean you are not allowed to do that but would like th know how you can make your tables fit nontheless?

Comment: I'm using LaTex first time. Not well versed with it at all. These are the packages I've used so far :\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

Comment: @Debbie - I've taken the liberty of copying the contents of your latest comment into the body of your query. There, it'll be seen and read more easily.

Comment: Thanks for adding the packages. `typearea` and `geometry` contradict each other. What kind of margin size do you actually want to have? The margin size crucially determines how much space is available for the tables and thus how one can make sure thex fit into the avialable space.

Comment: There's an edit in my question. Plz see once.

Comment: Your edit does address not @leandriis' comment that the settings of the `typearea` and `geometry` packages conflict with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\noindent\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
\hline
\textbf{Class}& \bfseries 1 & \bfseries 2 & \bfseries 3 & \bfseries4 & \bfseries 5 & \bfseries 6 & \bfseries 7 & \bfseries 8\\\hline
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.917 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo}
}
\hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
\hline

\textbf{Class}& \bfseries 1 & \bfseries 2 & \bfseries 3 & \bfseries 4 & \bfseries 5 & \bfseries 6 & \bfseries 7 & \bfseries 8\\\hline
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.917 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bar}
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:
I also propose this variant, which uses the`S` column type from `siunitx`:

```
\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
\noindent\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}S[table-format=1.4]|S[table-format=1.3]|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\bfseries Class}& \head{1} & \head{2} & \head{3} & \head{4} & \head{5}& \head{6} & \head{7}& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 8}\\ \hline
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.917 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Foo}
}
\hfill
\parbox{.45\linewidth}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}S[table-format=1.4]|S[table-format=1.3]|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\bfseries Class}& \head{1} & \head{2} & \head{3} & \head{4} & \head{5}& \head{6} & \head{7}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries 8}\\
\hline
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.917 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Bar}
}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion using `siunitx` for the alignment of the numbers, `booktabs` for the horizontal lines and `tabular*` to make sure the tables fit into the available space. Additionally, I have replaced the `\parbox` commands with two `minipage` environments:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{table-format=1}
    \caption{Foo}
    \label{tab:foo}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cSSSSS[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1.3]SS}
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class}\\
      \cmidrule{2-9}
      &  {1} &  {2} &  {3} &  {4} &  {5} &  {6} &  {7} &  {8}\\
      \midrule
      TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\
      TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{table-format=1}
    \caption{Bar}
    \label{tab:bar}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cSSSSS[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=1.3]SS}
      \toprule
      & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class}\\
      \cmidrule{2-9}
      &  {1} &  {2} &  {3} &  {4} &  {5} &  {6} &  {7} &  {8}\\
      \midrule
      TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\
      TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
      FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you re-organize the header material to that one sees only one instance of "Class" per table. I'd also get rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines in order to give the tables a more open and inviting "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by amssymb
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % ctan.org/pkg/mathtools 
%%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by mathtools
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Foo}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Bar}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```