# Caption and label of a table, of two tables kept side by side, is assigned to another table

Tags: tables, captions, minipage

I have created two table side by side with `minipage`. the tables appear perfectly except the label and caption for the right table show up as that of left table. On the other hand, the caption and label for right table vanish.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}


\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
Original Class & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class Predicted} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
1 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 14 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 11 & 0 & 0  \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13 & 0  \\
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 15  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab:Table 1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.475\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Evaluation Metrics}
\label{tab:Table 2}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit**

I used the answer written by Mico [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564282/5001).

**Edit 2**

I have used `[ht!]` for one table and the table was misplaced (Output attached). So I'm still using `[H]` which gives me desired output.

[image]

Comment: @Marijn : I've followed the answer written by Mico : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564278/how-can-i-reduce-the-sizes-of-the-tables-which-are-presented-side-by-side-their?noredirect=1#comment1422127_564278

Comment: unrelated but it's not normally good practice to have the table numbers numbers in `\label` as it confusers people reading the source if `\ref{tab:Table 2}` produces "Table 4" or whatever the number is in the final document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : is my question alright now?

Comment: yes thanks, I get same here, will look...

Comment: the issue is `\restylefloat{table}`

Comment: That makes `\caption` work as @Marijn described, the `\caption` is not used where it appears in the source but positioned according to the float style. If you want that generally but need special formatting here then that is probably possible I'd need to check the package but just removing that line gives the output you intended

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to achieve by running `\restylefloat{table}`.

Comment: Incidentally, the directive `\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}` directly contradicts the document class option `landscape`. Please settle the portrait versus landscape orientation issue.

Comment: @Mico my table was appearing before text. So I used \usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table} to use H as explained here so that table appears as instructed by my code but due to restylefloat that problem with caption started. Now after removing restylefloat the code works as I intended.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673942/latex-table-positioning

Comment: No you only need to load the package to use H restyling floats is more invasive it changes the way tables work, as you found

Comment: I've posted a comment below https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/564403/5001 to ask that the incorrect claim that `\restylefloat` is somehow needed in order to specify `[H]` be removed entirely.

Comment: Off-topic: Instead of `\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}`, do consider writing `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}`. Much more succinct, isn't it?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403661/how-to-prevent-floatrow-from-moving-the-caption/403662?r=SearchResults&s=2|42.1274#403662

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found out in the meantime, running `\restylefloat` is the cause of the odd-ball formatting issue you've encountered. Incidentally, it is *not true* that it's necessary to run `\restylefloat` in order to use the `[H]` positioning specifier with `table` or `figure` floats. That said, you should really ask yourself if you're doing the right thing -- typographically speaking -- by using `[H]` at all, as its use can have some unexpected negative side-effects. Everything good about `[H]` can also be achieved with `[ht!]`. For a longer discussion of this issue, see ['h' float specifier changed to 'ht' warning when not attempting to specify a float](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1511/5001).

As you've probably also noticed by now, if two `minipage` environments of unequal heights are placed side by side, their default vertical orientation is to align them verically in the middle. If this is not desired and, say, if you prefer top-alignment, just specify `[t]` ("top") for both `minipage` as well as for both `tabular*` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,%landscape % <-- landscape option is overridden
     ]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%%\usepackage{amsmath}  % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%\usepackage{amsmath} % don't load packages twice
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%%\usepackage{float}   % you don't really need this package
%%%\restylefloat{table} % don't do this


\begin{document}    
\begin{table}[ht!]  % much safer than "[H]"
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
Orig.\ Class & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class Predicted} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
1 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 14 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 17 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 15 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 11 & 0 & 0  \\
7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 13 & 0  \\
8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 15  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Confusion Matrix}
\label{tab:Table1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\textwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{8}{c}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{Class} \\
\cmidrule{2-9}
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8  \\
\midrule
TPR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  & 0.917  & 1 & 1 \\
TNR & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0.99 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
FPR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.0095 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
FNR & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.083 & 0 & 0  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\caption{Evaluation Metrics}
\label{tab:Table2}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer solved my purpose. Also thanks for pointing out unnecessary/redundant use of packages. I removed them. Plz look into Edit 2 portion in my question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a hidden feature in `float` that, when you do `\restylefloat`, the `\caption` command changes in a peculiar way: it stores its argument in a box which is assigned globally; only at `\end{table}` the box is used, which means that the first caption has been forgotten.

The package does so because it wants to enforce top or bottom position of the caption independently on the position the code for `\caption` is typed at. In the case of the `plain` style the position is bottom.

The effect of this is that after `\restylefloat{table}` you *cannot* use `minipage` to set two tables side by side.

Too bad, I agree.

On the other hand, you don't need to `\restylefloat` if you want to use `[H]` and you *don't* want to use `[H]` under any circumstances.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Plz look into the edit 2 portion of my question.

Comment: @Debbie Move the code for the table earlier in the document, add also `b` to the options. When the document is in final form, as far as text is concerned, you may need to add `\clearpage` before the references. Don’t work on float positioning until your document is in final form, as a general rule.