# Captioning two minipages in custom float

Tags: floats, captions, minipage

I am trying to put two listings side by side in a custom float using the `float` package using `minipage`s. What I am trying to do works fine inside a `figure` (both captions appear) but inside my custom `code` environment only the second ("Listing 2") caption appears.

[image: MWE]

**MWE**:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{code}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{code}{Listing}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{code}[t]
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \captionof{lstlisting}{Disappears}
    Inside custom 1
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \captionof{lstlisting}{Appears}
    Inside custom 2
    \end{minipage}
\end{code}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \caption{Appears}
    Inside figure 1
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \caption{Appears}
    Inside figure 2
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: this was asked yesterday as well `\floatstyle{plaintop}` means you can only have one caption per float, placed on top.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564413/1090

Comment: Thanks! Is there any alternative then, to have multiple captions on top?

Comment: if you don't use restylefloat then the captions go where you put them, they are not moved, so just place them where you want.

Comment: If I delete the floatstyle then this happens: https://i.imgur.com/60OCzyt.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using the `newfloat` environment:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=frm,placement={tph},name=Frame]{myfloat}

…

\begin{myfloat}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \captionof{lstlisting}{Appears}
    Inside custom 1
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \captionof{lstlisting}{Appears}
    Inside custom 2
    \end{minipage}
\end{myfloat}
```